# Removing a part of a string

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, replace

```
DECLARE 
    @A VARCHAR(MAX),
    @StartPosistion int,
    @StringLen int

Select -- Setting up the strings to split (details)
    @StartPosistion = charindex('Eye Colour:', details),
    @StringLen = patindex('%'+CHAR(10)+'%',substring(details,@StartPosistion ,len(details)))
FROM 
    XXX.XXX --Table/Database

SELECT
    substring(XXX.XXX ,@StartPosistion ,@StringLen-1 ) AS EyeColour,
```

Essentially I have a column in a table called 'details', which is usually filled with all sorts of information such as:

```
Name: Person Person
Age: 40
Hair Colour: Blue
Eye Colour: Red
```

I know ideally this information should be stored as seperate columns, but lets assume there is no choice for whatever reason. To get back just the eye colour of a certain person, I could run the above code which looks for a starting position, in this case the words 'Eye Colour:' and then shows me everything in that one line while removing all the unndeeded information around it.

Essentially, running the bottom select statement will give me the output 'Eye Colour: Red', but what if I wanted to remove the word 'Eye Colour:' so that the only thing that outputs is the word 'Red'. Is there a way of going about with this without overcomplicating the code? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you can make a simple replace. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Comment: please give the exact value coming in the column, at least two..

Comment: Two examples of data in the details column would be:

Name: John Bishop
Age: 40
Hair Colour: Blue
Eye Colour: Red
Weight: 120kg

AND

Name: Tim Tom
Age: 19
Hair Colour: Brown
Eye Colour: Black
Weight: 90kg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When You use charindex('Eye Colour:', details) the charindex will return starting postion of Eye Colour, but ideally you need location after Eye coluor so you can just hard code 11+1, 11 being the length of 'Eye Colour:' and Plus 1 for actual starting postion of RED.

can you please give the details of on value so that i can help better.

Regards

Ashutosh Arya

Comment: Ah of course, I was thinking about this in the wrong way, thanks a lot for the answer! I did as you suggested and it is working great. Just a quick question though, in terms of performance would you say your way is better compared to adding a replace statement somewhere? My guess is, hard coding the position would be better since doing a replace will end up using more resources. What do you think?

Comment: Welcome :) Hard coding is good is this case as the incoming coulumn will al ways be like this only, even if you use replace you have to hard code the values saying replace 'Eye Colour:' with sothing say','. More over performance wise both are almost same, an Index on this column will help. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the search string in the results you already have

with "substring(XXX.XXX ,@StartPosistion ,@StringLen-1 ) AS EyeColour" you're getting "Eye Colour: Red"

so around that...

```
Replace (substring(XXX.XXX ,@StartPosistion ,@StringLen-1 ), 'Eye Colour: ', '') AS EyeColourValueOnly
```